# Changing container managed authentification alias

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I'm using WebSphere 7.0.0.37 and jython

I need to change the 'Container-managed authentication alias', unfortunatelly I can't find anything in API, inspecting attributes of existing DataSources or any example for that task.

I have succesfully changed the 'composant-managed authentication alias'  with:

`AdminConfig.modify(DataSourceProvider, '[[name "basename"] [authDataAlias "' +  nameNode + '/' + aliasJaas + '" ] ')`

How can i do that?

thank you!

Comment: Note that if you can figure out how to do something in the Admin Console, you can use the "Command Assist" function to get a Jython snippet to do the equivalent via wsadmin.   See [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0812_rhodes/0812_rhodes.html).     I posted a snippet below as answer that hopefully solves your problem (though it's not really an exhaustive, complete answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some logic which you could use to solve your problem.

```py
# Create new alias
cellName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(AdminConfig.list("Cell"), "name") 
security = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:' + cellName + '/Security:/')
myAlias = 'blahAlias'
user = 'blah'
pswd = 'blah'
jaasAttrs = [['alias', myAlias], ['userId', user], ['password', pswd ]]
print AdminConfig.create('JAASAuthData', security, jaasAttrs)
print "Alias = "  + myAlias + " was created."

# Get a reference to your DataSource (assume you know how to do this):
myDS = ...

# Set new alias on DataSource
AdminConfig.modify('MappingModule', myDS, '[[authDataAlias ' + myAlias + '] [mappingConfigAlias DefaultPrincipalMapping]]')
```

Note that if you can figure out how to do a given task in the Admin Console, you can use the "Command Assist" function to get a Jython snippet to do the equivalent via wsadmin. See [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0812_rhodes/0812_rhodes.html).